# Conditionally rendered ref not available in effect that depends on same condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs

From my understanding of how the React lifecycle works, if something is conditionally rendered, the ref callback should be fired every time it is remade, and that should happen before any effect based on the same condition is fired.

So in the following code:

```
const OuterComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (open) {
      // always logs { current: none }
      console.log(ref);
    }
  }, [open]);

  return <InnerComponent open={open} ref={ref} />;
};

const InnerComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  if (!props.open) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div ref={ref} />;
});
```

as I understood it, when `setOpen(true)` is run:

1. both components rerender - because open is now true, InnerComponent renders the div with the ref on it
2. the ref callback on the div in InnerComponent is fired, setting that ref to a reference to that div
3. the effect in OuterComponent is then fired because open has changed, now with the ref defined

But the result of that log in the effect seems to always be { current: null } implying I've either misunderstood the lifecycle, or I've set this up wrong, or forwardRef makes this setup behave differently.

Can someone set me straight and tell me why that ref isn't defined when the effect runs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So from further investigation, it looks like effects are actually fired **before** ref callbacks, so the answer was to add the stuff that depends on the ref into a callback, and then pass that callback as if it was a ref

so:

```
const OuterComponent = () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const setRef = useCallback((node) => {
    ref.current = node;
    if (open) {
      // always logs the DOM node, or undefined if it's being unmounted
      console.log(node);
    }
  }, [open]);

  return <InnerComponent open={open} ref={setRef} />;
};

const InnerComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  if (!props.open) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div ref={ref} />;
});
```

This ensures the ref is still set properly, and ensures that anything that needs to run that depends on the ref can still run.

It feels a bit janky but I found a tweet from Dan Abramov himself endorsing this approach so I'll take his word on it that it's cool

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [enter link description here](https://dmitripavlutin.com/react-useref-guide/) this article on the `useRef` hook, it looks like it wants to be passed in an initial state like this:

```
const ref = useRef(initialStateHere);
```

**EDIT**
I went and double checked after your comment and you can definitely use the hook without an argument. That's my bad.

Looks like you figured it out but obviously I'll leave this up.

**EDIT**

Additionally here:

```
const InnerComponent = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  if (!props.open) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div ref={ref} />;
});
```

You can destruction the props in the parameters for `InnerComponent` like this: **EDITED**

```
const InnerComponent = forwardRef(({ open }, ref) => {
  if (!open) {
    return null;
  }
  return <div ref={ref} />;
});
```

Comment: the initial state isn't available during the first render as it's set by the ref prop on the div in the InnerComponent

Comment: @PatrickBenjamin I see what you're saying. That's my fault I definitely misunderstood the hook arguments. I have edited my answer so no one else gets confused.